# Python broken on upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu

Hi I am trying to update Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 LTS via "do-release-upgrade" but still got:

```
2016-08-18 18:40:08,938 INFO apt version: '0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.27'
2016-08-18 18:40:08,938 INFO python version: '2.7.12 (default, Jul 18 2016, 14:59:49) 
[GCC 4.6.3]'
2016-08-18 18:40:08,939 INFO release-upgrader version '0.220.3' started
2016-08-18 18:40:08,940 INFO locale: 'en_US' 'UTF-8'
2016-08-18 18:40:08,999 DEBUG Using 'DistUpgradeViewText' view
2016-08-18 18:40:09,025 DEBUG aufsOptionsAndEnvironmentSetup()
2016-08-18 18:40:09,027 DEBUG using '/tmp/upgrade-rw-xlP_6c' as aufs_rw_dir
2016-08-18 18:40:09,027 DEBUG using '/tmp/upgrade-chroot-RJMewm' as aufs chroot dir
2016-08-18 18:40:09,027 DEBUG enable dpkg --force-overwrite
2016-08-18 18:40:09,072 DEBUG creating statefile: '/var/log/dist-upgrade/apt-clone_system_state.tar.gz'
2016-08-18 18:40:10,482 DEBUG lsb-release: 'precise'
2016-08-18 18:40:11,766 ERROR not handled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/update-manager-W9tKZ8/trusty", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())

  File "/tmp/update-manager-W9tKZ8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeMain.py", line 244, in main
    if app.run():

  File "/tmp/update-manager-W9tKZ8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1827, in run
    return self.fullUpgrade()

  File "/tmp/update-manager-W9tKZ8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 1649, in fullUpgrade
    if not self.prepare():

  File "/tmp/update-manager-W9tKZ8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 441, in prepare
    self._sshMagic()

  File "/tmp/update-manager-W9tKZ8/DistUpgrade/DistUpgradeController.py", line 317, in _sshMagic
    "-p",str(port)])

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

2016-08-18 18:40:11,767 DEBUG enabling apt cron job
```

Cant get any information on web to fix this. I already updated python 2.7.3 to python 2.7.11, tried linking to python3. Still the same issue...

Any ideas?

Comment: This would be a better fit for the ask Ubuntu stack exchange.  Are you doing an update over ssh? It is trying, and failing, to start a second sshd.

Comment: tried both via ssh an direct shell. every time the same issue. also cleaned /tmp/up*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already "fixed" this issue by killing sshd directly, hardly reinstalled python2.7.12 by compiling from source.

Got some python errors on end of upgrade... After upgrading everything seems to be fine.